# Deserializing a Map<String, Object> field with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a User object with this structure:

```
class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    // GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

I have a JSON String with this structure:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id:"123456789",
        "name:"azerty",
        "emailHash":"123456789", // not used in User class
        "properties": {
            "p1":1,
            "p2":"test",
            "p3":[1, 2, 3, 4],
            "p4":{
               etc...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Properties' keys are String, Properties' values can be a String, int, Array, boolean, Map etc.

I try to deserialize this JSON string with Gson like that:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsonString);
JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
Gson gson = builder.create();
User user = (User) gson.fromJson(object.get("user"), new TypeToken<User>() {}.getType());
```

Fields 'id' and 'name' are correctly injected but the field 'properties' stays null.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would suggest having properties as `JsonObject` and then converting the JSON directly to `Map<String,Object>`.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine with one small problem: you seem to have created a `GsonBuilder` named `builder` but are then using one named `gsonBuilder`. If that's actually compiling then you have another `GsonBuilder` you previously created and are using it by mistake. Other than that ... it deserializes fine on my machine.

Comment: `gsonBuilder` is an error when I write the topic. It's `builder` that I use in my code. I'll edit my topic for correction. The `properties` field is correctly injected in your test? It's very strange it stays to null for me...

Comment: Did you tried: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();? Works for me in the same situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("bobi.json"));
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    User user = gson.fromJson(reader, User.class);
    System.out.println(user.getName());
    System.out.println(user.getId());
    for (String property : user.getProperties().keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + property + " value: " + user.getProperties().get(property));
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Prints this:

```
azerty
123456789
Key: p1 value: 1.0
Key: p2 value: test
Key: p3 value: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Key: p4 value: {}
```

However, keep in mind that I have stripped the wrapping json object in the file I parse. The file is:

```
{
        "id":"123456789",
        "name" : "azerty",
        "emailHash":"123456789", 
        "properties": {
            "p1":1,
            "p2":"test",
            "p3":[1, 2, 3, 4],
            "p4":{

            }
        }
}
```

Also I added closing double quote for `name` and `id`, which you did not have in your sample.

The `User` class as requested by the OP. I have added getters and setters for the reason of printing:

```
import java.util.Map;

class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the `user` object that you used? I try your code but `properties` is always `null`... I'm on JDK7 and Gson 2.2.2 if I can help...

Comment: @FranckYapadesouciAnso: Added. Gson 2.1, java 1.7

Comment: Ok I found my mistake. It was the FieldNamingPolicy the problem. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day!

Comment: @FranckYapadesouciAnso: How did it affect the parsing?

Comment: In fact, it's my fault. For the topic I simplified field name. The `property`field in the topic is `dynProp` in my code. The field naming policy set on `LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` try to search `dyn_prop` in the json and not `dynProp`. So I switch the naming policy to `IDENTITY` and now it works!

Comment: @FranckYapadesouciAnso: Btw identity is the default field naming policy, you do not need to specify it. Also, I can see you are new around here. If I helped you accept and upvote my answer - this is how SO is meant to work.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but I can't upvote. I have not enough reputations. Sorry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for after many years... did you try: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create(); ??