# GSON Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT?

Tags: java, android, web-services, gson

I just start to learn about gson.
I see lot of topic about this error, but i don't find any help or answer corresponding of my problem.

I'm trying to parse a JSON string like this one:

```
{
"CodeAnalytique": "XXXX",
  "Domaine": "XXXX",
  "HabilitationAD": [
    {
      "Key": "XXXX",
      "Value": [
        {
          "Applicatif": "XXXX",
          "Cle": "E",
          "Role": "Red",
          "Valeur": "XXXX"
        },
        {
          "Applicatif": "XXXX",
          "Cle": "E",
          "Role": "Red",
          "Valeur": "XXXX"
        }
        //lot of other value
        ]
    }
  ],
  "HabilitationInterprete": [
    {
      "Key": "XX",
      "Value": [
        {
          "Applicatif": "XXXX",
          "Cle": "Z",
          "Role": "Red",
          "Valeur": "XXX"
        },
        {
          "Applicatif": "XXXX",
          "Cle": "Z",
          "Role": "Red",
          "Valeur": "XXXX"
        }
        //lot of other value
        ]
    }
  ],
  "Identity": "XXXX",
  "InfoConsolidee": "Operation requested at XXXX",
  "IsAdminI": true,
  "IsAdminM": false,
  "IsAuthentif": true,
  "Matricule": "XXX",
  "Nom": "XXXX",
  "PasswordEnvoye": "XXXX",
  "Prenom": "XXX",
  "PrincipalPermissionMode": 1,
  "RoleSGBD": [
    "xxxx"
  ],
  "RoleSI": [
    null,
    "APP_02",
    "APP_03",
   //lot of other value
  ],
  "Societe": "XXX",
  "TypeClient": null
}
```

into an objects

```
InfoSecuriteBean mInfoSecuriteBean = gson.fromJson(reader, InfoSecuriteBean.class);
```

Here's object class I'm using.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class InfoSecuriteBean {

    @SerializedName("IsAuthentif")
    private boolean mIsAuthentif = false;

    @SerializedName("PrincipalPermissionMode")
    private enumPrincipalPermissionMode mPrincipalPermissionMode;
    @SerializedName("RoleSGBD")
    private List<String> mRoleSGBD;
    @SerializedName("RoleSI")
    private List<String> mRoleSI;
    @SerializedName("Identity")
    private String mIdentity = null;
    @SerializedName("Password")
    private String mPassword = null;
    @SerializedName("InfoConsolidee")
    private String mInfoConsolidee = null;

    @SerializedName("IsAdminM")
    private boolean mIsAdminM = false;
    @SerializedName("IsAdminI")
    private boolean mIsAdminI = false;

    @SerializedName("Matricule")
    private String mMatricule = null;
    @SerializedName("Nom")
    private String mNom = null;
    @SerializedName("Prenom")
    private String mPrenom = null;
    @SerializedName("CodeAnalytique")
    private String mCodeAnalytique = null;
    @SerializedName("Domaine")
    private String mDomaine = null;
    @SerializedName("Societe")
    private String mSociete = null;
    @SerializedName("TypeClient")
    private String mTypeClient = null;

    @SerializedName("HabilitationAD")
    private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationAD = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
    @SerializedName("HabilitationInterprete")
    private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationInterprete = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
//Getter and setter
```

and the other object use

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class HabilitationBean
{
    @SerializedName("Applicatif")
    private String mApplicatif = null;
    @SerializedName("Role")
    private String mRole = null;
    @SerializedName("Cle")
    private String mCle = null;
    @SerializedName("Valeur")
    private String mValeur = null;

//getter and setter
```

But it throws me with

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECTat line 1 column 60
```

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 60 path $.HabilitationAD[0]
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:748)
            at com.sig.webservice.WebSecurityGBD.doInBackground(WebSecurityGBD.java:69)
            at com.sig.webservice.WebSecurityGBD.doInBackground(WebSecurityGBD.java:23)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 60 path $.HabilitationAD[0]
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:748)
            at com.sig.webservice.WebSecurityGBD.doInBackground(WebSecurityGBD.java:69)
            at com.sig.webservice.WebSecurityGBD.doInBackground(WebSecurityGBD.java:23)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT 2**

The problem come from the two HashMap>

```
 @SerializedName("HabilitationAD")
        private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationAD = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
        @SerializedName("HabilitationInterprete")
        private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationInterprete = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
```

if i comment this properties i don't have any probleme to build my json objet.

I found this link [Deserializing a Map<String, Object> field with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263114/deserializing-a-mapstring-object-field-with-gson)

Currently i try something like this

```
public class InfoSecuriteBeanDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InfoSecuriteBean> {

    @Override
    public InfoSecuriteBean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) json;

        InfoSecuriteBean mInfoSecuriteBean = new InfoSecuriteBean();

        for (int i=1; i<jArray.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) jArray.get(i);
            //assuming you have the suitable constructor...
            HabilitationBean mHabilitationBean = new HabilitationBean(jObject.get("Applicatif").getAsString(),
                    jObject.get("Cle").getAsString(),
                    jObject.get("Role").getAsString(),
                    jObject.get("Valeur").getAsString());
            mInfoSecuriteBean.getmHabilitationAD().add(mHabilitationBean);
        }

        return mInfoSecuriteBean;
    }
}
```

Do you think i'm in the good way to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simply solution for solve my problem. I will show here my solution, maybe this will help some people.

So I created two new class : HabilitationAD and HabilitationInterprete

```
public class HabilitationAD {

    @SerializedName("Key")
    private String mKey;

    @SerializedName("Value")
    private List<BeanHabilitation> mValue;

    public String getmKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    public void setmKey(String mKey) {
        this.mKey = mKey;
    }

    public List<BeanHabilitation> getmValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setmValue(List<BeanHabilitation> mValue) {
        this.mValue = mValue;
    }

    public HabilitationAD(){

    }

    public HabilitationAD(String p_mKey, List<BeanHabilitation> p_mValue){
        this.mKey = p_mKey;
        this.mValue = p_mValue;
    }
}
```

and :

```
    public class HabilitationInterprete {

        @SerializedName("Key")
        private String mKey;

        @SerializedName("Value")
        private List<BeanHabilitation> mValue;

        public String getmKey() {
            return mKey;
        }

        public void setmKey(String mKey) {
            this.mKey = mKey;
        }

        public List<BeanHabilitation> getmValue() {
            return mValue;
        }

        public void setmValue(List<BeanHabilitation> mValue) {
            this.mValue = mValue;
        }

 public HabilitationInterprete(){

    }

    public HabilitationInterprete(String p_mKey, List<BeanHabilitation> p_mValue){
        this.mKey = p_mKey;
        this.mValue = p_mValue;
    }
```

And I modify my class `InfoSecuriteBean`

I changed this :

```
 @SerializedName("HabilitationAD")
    private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationAD = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
    @SerializedName("HabilitationInterprete")
    private Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>> mHabilitationInterprete = new HashMap<String, List<HabilitationBean>>();
```

by this :

```
@SerializedName("HabilitationAD")
    private List<HabilitationAD> habilitationAD;
    @SerializedName("HabilitationInterprete")
    private List<HabilitationInterprete> habilitationInterprete;
```

Now all work great ! Hope this solution will help !

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade to the latest Gson and it'll tell you exactly where there's a mismatch. Typically this happens when your model has a `List` but your JSON doesn't (ie. no `[...]`).

Comment: I have the last version of Gson. See my edit for log

Answer (score 0):

the error you're getting is pretty standard. Gson cannot deserialize nested objects. Gotta write your own adapters.

So you have to learn how to write a custom deserializer (very easy) and then register it when you create your gson object.

Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Thanks mehdi for your answer ! I'll try to find some example to write a custom deserializer and how to implement in my code.

Comment: Gson can deserialize nested objects.

Comment: I'm seeing where you're coming from but in their website, they say write your own stuff. Yet I see sometimes examples of this working. How can you do it ? (Like op's example for ex...)

Comment: @mehdi can you help me to deserialize `Map<String,List<HabilitationBean>>` from the json ?

Comment: You're almost there I think.Just create a new map with its proper String. Then create a new list of HabBean, and add with the 'for' all the elements from the jsonObj in the list (like ur EDIT 2).
Lastly, set the map key to the string, and its value to the list.

Step by step, easy.