# Google gson Syntax Error

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Im trying to put Map into listMap using gson and view it in listView. I have problem on how to use it. 
Here my code (button onClick):

```
map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("title",edttext1.getText().toString());
map.put("des",edittext2.getText().toString());
listmap1 = Gson().fromGson(new Gson().toJson(map), new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
 map.clear();
```

after catch the Exception, i got this:
[image: error]

Im going to save the json string to SharedPreferenced so i need to use this.Thanks.

Comment: GSON was expecting an *array* but got an *object* instead. Recheck your JSON and make sure you provide an array where needed.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570343/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object

Comment: instead of adding map , add the arraylist here - toJson(map) , toJson(list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSON was expecting an array but it's got object only.