# How to create a pojoclass having dynamic key

Tags: android, json, gson

How can i create a pojo class from the below responses of same url.

RESPONSE 1:
{
           "info": {
               "price": 1,
               "map": {
                   "1": 1,
                   "2": 2,
                   "3": 1,
                   "5": 0.5,
                   "6": 3,
                   "7": 5
               },
               "value": 0
   }
}

RESPONSE 2:
{
           "info": {
               "price": 1,
               "map": {
                   "1": 1,
                   "2": 6,
                   "3": 4,
                },
               "value": 1
   }
}

here the keys inside the "map" Json object is dynamic. Please help me to create a pojoclass with dynamic key(inside map eg:1,2,3...).

Answer (score 3):

Finally got my answer by using

```
private Map<String, Float> map;

public Map<String, Float> getMap() {
return map;
}
```

inside POJO class.

And i called the POJO inside Activity by

```
Map<String, Float> maps =POJOclass.getMap();
for (String mapKey :  maps.keySet()) {
Log.d("Map","mapKey : "+mapKey+" , mapValue : "+maps.get(mapKey)):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Gson to parse it to a map.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, int>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(response, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can opt for Dynamic POJO Creation in your application.

http://blog.javaforge.net/post/31913732423/howto-create-java-pojo-at-runtime-with-javassist

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify the response you are receiving to

```
{ "info": { "price": 1, "map": 
[ {"key":"1","value": "1"},{"key":"2","value":2},...], "value": 0 } }
```

then you can work it out using the below POJOs

```
public class Info {
  @SerializedName("price")
  private String price;

  @SerializedName("map")
  private ArrayList<MapEntry> map;

  @SerializedName("value")
  private String value; 

}

public class MapEntry{
  @SerializedName("key")
  private String key;

  @SerializedName("value")
  private String value;

}
```

Comment: Is there no other way, without changing the response ? @hars

Comment: i think de-serializing it as a map can make this work for you. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263114/deserializing-a-mapstring-object-field-with-gson

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. But i tried a different method , I used 
    private Map<String, Float> map;
in pojo class